# Получение данных из сокета через ip

Tags: python, сокет

я пишу скрипт, который получает данные от другой программы через ip с помощью следующей функции. В первых двух байтах закодировано, какая должна быть длина сообщения, поэтому сначала считываются первые два байта, а затем, если длина пришедшего сообщения больше получившегося числа - сообщение считается пришедшим.
Проблема связанна с тем, что программа выкидывает сообщения каждую секунду, а скрипт считывает только первое.

```
def ip_connect(self):

    bind_ip = '127.0.0.1'
    bind_port = 12345

    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.bind((bind_ip, bind_port))
    server.listen(5)  # max backlog of connections

    print('Listening on {}:{}'.format(bind_ip, bind_port))

    def handle_client_connection(client_socket):

        request = client_socket.recv(1024)
        len_message = int.from_bytes(request[:2], 'big')
        if len(request) > len_message:
            message = request[2:]
        print(codecs.decode(message, 'UTF-8'))

    while True:
        print('123')
        client_sock, address = server.accept()
        print ('Accepted connection from {}:{}'.format(address[0], address[1]))
        client_handler = threading.Thread(
            target = handle_client_connection,
            args = (client_sock,)  # without comma you'd get a... TypeError: handle_client_connection() argument after * must be a sequence, not _socketobject
        )
        client_handler.start()
```

Comment: Как минимум, вы не очень аккуратно работаете с recv: он вполне может вернуть несколько сообщений одновременно (особенно если они присланы одновременно и/или умещаются в MTU), или наоброт вернуть неполный кусок от первого сообщения. Нужно тщательно проверять длину возвращаемых recv'ом данных, а не надеяться на авось что `request[2:]` будет одним сообщением

Answer (score 0):

Я переписал свою функцию получения данных следующим образом, все работает корректно:

```
def ip_connect():

    HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost)
    PORT = 12345       # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:

        s.bind((HOST, PORT))
        s.listen()
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        with conn:

            print('Connected by', addr)

            while True:

                request = conn.recv(1024)
                msg_size = 0
                if msg_size == 0:

                    if len(request) < 2:

                        pass

                    else:

                        len_message = int.from_bytes(request[:2], 'big')

                        if len(request) < len_message:

                            pass

                        else:

                            message = request[2:]
                            message = codecs.decode(message, 'UTF-8')
                            message = message[1 : -1]
                            msg_to_list = message.split(',')
                            data = []
                            for msg in msg_to_list:

                                msg = msg.split(':')
                                msg = msg[1][1:-1]
                                data.append(msg)
                                msg_size == 0

                if not data:

                    break
```